# I want to send multiple sms with nexmo cURL

Tags: curl, sms, php-curl, vonage, bulksms

```
curl -X "POST" "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json" \
 -d "from=testsms" \
 -d "text=hello" \
 -d "to=44xxxxxxxxxx” \
 -d "api_key=xxxxxxxx" \
 -d "api_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I want to send multiple SMS so basically bulk SMS but it does not allow more than 1 number in the -d "to=44xxxxxxxxxx” \ bit so can someone please help me fix this. I will place a few links to see what is happening

https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/205065817-How-to-Send-Multiple-SMS-in-a-Single-API-Request

please use that link to guide the answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Each API call can only send one SMS. The article describes how to keep the connection open between sends but the API is also rate-limited so this may not help. This isn't the answer you were looking for but you will need to handle a queue or something yourself, and trickle the messages into the API one-by-one.

Comment: do you think you can help me out there? I'm not too good with that. I understand that you can send the SMS to 30 numbers a second and to do that you need to keep the connection open. If you can help it will be very appreciated